# how to add .js file to jsp page after ajax call

Tags: javascript

I am using spring MVC(java) for making web application.

I want help regarding to dynamically add .js file after ajax call.

In my project there are 3 main part which are fix

1. Header
2. Left panel
3. Footer.

left panel contains menu.

when I click on any menu it will load whole module using AJAX in middle content div.

now problem is how can I load that module's js after AJAX call?

if I keep all js at beginning then there is a huge overload & may be conflicts of any functions also.

So I want to add js file after AJAX call.

So is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"may be conflicts of any functions also"* ... same conflicts will occur loading later. Need to structure all the javascript so conflicts won't occur

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `script` element and add it to the `body` of your application, something like this:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.onload = function(){ console.log('script loaded')};
link.src = 'your script location';
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: this is helpful to me but is there any possibilities to duplicate .js file when I load same module after visited few modules?

Comment: The cache of the browser should sort out this problem, if you declare it as a `link`